# Pthreads- Mutex Locks but variables don't change

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm writing an extremely simple program to demonstrate a Pthreads implementation I ported from C++ back to C.

I create two lock-step threads and give them two jobs

One increments a1 once per step

One decrements a2 once per step

During the synchronized phase (When the mutexes are locked for both t1 and t2) I compare a1 and a2 to see if we should stop stepping.

I'm wondering if i'm going crazy here because not only does the variable *not always change after stepping and locking* but they sometimes *change at different rates* as if the threads were running even after the locks.

EDIT: Yes, I did research this. Yes, the C++ implementation works. Yes, the C++ implementation is nearly identical to this one, but I had to cast PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER and PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER in c and pass this as the first argument to every function. I spent a while trying to debug this (short of whipping out gdb) to no avail.

```
#ifndef LOCKSTEPTHREAD_H
#define LOCKSTEPTHREAD_H
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
    pthread_cond_t myCond;
    pthread_t myThread;
    int isThreadLive;
    int shouldKillThread;
    void (*execute)();
} lsthread;
void init_lsthread(lsthread* t);
void start_lsthread(lsthread* t);
void kill_lsthread(lsthread* t);
void kill_lsthread_islocked(lsthread* t);
void lock(lsthread* t);
void step(lsthread* t);
void* lsthread_func(void* me_void);
#ifdef LOCKSTEPTHREAD_IMPL
//function declarations

void init_lsthread(lsthread* t){
    //pthread_mutex_init(&(t->myMutex), NULL);
    //pthread_cond_init(&(t->myCond), NULL);
    t->myMutex = (pthread_mutex_t)PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    t->myCond = (pthread_cond_t)PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    t->isThreadLive = 0;
    t->shouldKillThread = 0;
    t->execute = NULL;
}
void destroy_lsthread(lsthread* t){
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&t->myMutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&t->myCond);
}
void kill_lsthread_islocked(lsthread* t){
    if(!t->isThreadLive)return;
    //lock(t);
    t->shouldKillThread = 1;
    step(t);
    pthread_join(t->myThread,NULL);
    t->isThreadLive = 0;
    t->shouldKillThread = 0;
}

void kill_lsthread(lsthread* t){
    if(!t->isThreadLive)return;
    lock(t);
    t->shouldKillThread = 1;
    step(t);
    pthread_join(t->myThread,NULL);
    t->isThreadLive = 0;
    t->shouldKillThread = 0;
}
void lock(lsthread* t){
    if(pthread_mutex_lock(&t->myMutex))
        puts("\nError locking mutex.");
}

void step(lsthread* t){
    if(pthread_cond_signal(&(t->myCond)))
        puts("\nError signalling condition variable");
    if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&(t->myMutex)))
        puts("\nError unlocking mutex");
}
void* lsthread_func(void* me_void){
    lsthread* me = (lsthread*) me_void;
    int ret;
    if (!me)pthread_exit(NULL);
    if(!me->execute)pthread_exit(NULL);
    while (!(me->shouldKillThread)) {
        ret = pthread_cond_wait(&(me->myCond), &(me->myMutex));
        if(ret)pthread_exit(NULL);
        if (!(me->shouldKillThread) && me->execute)
            me->execute();
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void start_lsthread(lsthread* t){
    if(t->isThreadLive)return;
    t->isThreadLive = 1;
    t->shouldKillThread = 0;
    pthread_create(
        &t->myThread,
        NULL,
        lsthread_func,
        (void*)t
    );
}
#endif
#endif
```

This is my driver program:

```
#define LOCKSTEPTHREAD_IMPL
#include "include/lockstepthread.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
unsigned char a1, a2;
void JobThread1(){
    unsigned char copy = a1;
    copy++;
    a1 = copy;
}
void JobThread2(){
    unsigned char copy = a2;
    copy--;
    a2 = copy;
}
int main(){
    char inputline[2048];
    inputline[2047] = '\0';
    lsthread t1, t2;
    init_lsthread(&t1);
    init_lsthread(&t2);
    t1.execute = JobThread1;
    t2.execute = JobThread2;
    printf(
    "\nThis program demonstrates threading by having"
    "\nTwo threads \"walk\" toward each other using unsigned chars."
    "\nunsigned Integer overflow guarantees the two will converge."
    );
    printf("\nEnter a number for thread 1 to process: ");
    fgets(inputline, 2047,stdin);
    a1 = (unsigned char)atoi(inputline);
    printf("\nEnter a number for thread 2 to process: ");
    fgets(inputline, 2047,stdin);
    a2 = (unsigned char)atoi(inputline);
    start_lsthread(&t1);
    start_lsthread(&t2);
    unsigned int i = 0;
    lock(&t1);
    lock(&t2);
    do{
        printf("\n%u: a1 = %d, a2 = %d",i++,(int)a1,(int)a2);
        fflush(stdout);
        step(&t1);
        step(&t2);
        lock(&t1);
        lock(&t2);
    }while(a1 < a2);
    kill_lsthread_islocked(&t1);
    kill_lsthread_islocked(&t2);
    destroy_lsthread(&t1);
    destroy_lsthread(&t2);
    return 0;
}
```

Example program usage:

```
Enter a number for thread 1 to process: 5

Enter a number for thread 2 to process: 10

0: a1 = 5, a2 = 10
1: a1 = 5, a2 = 10
2: a1 = 5, a2 = 10
3: a1 = 5, a2 = 10
4: a1 = 5, a2 = 10
5: a1 = 5, a2 = 10
6: a1 = 6, a2 = 9
7: a1 = 6, a2 = 9
8: a1 = 7, a2 = 9
9: a1 = 7, a2 = 9
10: a1 = 7, a2 = 9
11: a1 = 7, a2 = 9
12: a1 = 8, a2 = 9
```

So, what's the deal?

Comment: You should read the manpages for `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_signal()`. And by read, I mean *read carefully, as if you were trying to really understand them*.

Comment: I've read it several times now. Yes, I spent a while staring at the man page when I wrote the C++ implementation. I'm staring at it again.
When it gets invoked the mutex is released by the calling thread so it can be locked by another.
When it returns, the mutex is locked by the calling thread.
Pthread_cond_signal allows pthread_cond_wait to move on to the next iteration.
I spent quite a while playing with it.

Comment: Reading comprehension seems to be a bit of a weakness then. [POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) "When using condition variables there is always a boolean predicate involving shared variables associated with each condition wait that is true if the thread should proceed. Spurious wakeups from the pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() functions may occur. "

Comment: So am I making an obvious mistake?
Could you help me instead of giving me riddles?
I don't understand the bit about spurious wakeups. is that what's happening?

Comment: A condition variable is not a semaphore.

Comment: What is a semaphore?

Comment: I googled what a semaphore is.
Yeah that's what the mutex is for
the mutex is the semaphor guarding the shared variables

Comment: [POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sem_trywait.html) A semaphore is an atomic counter that will cause a thread to suspend if the thread attempts to decrement the counter while the count is non-positive, and allows suspended threads to be awoken when the count is incremented again.

Comment: So if you know so much how can I achieve what I want to do

Comment: I'm not sure I even know what it is that you want to do. Assuming you want to have threads execute in lockstep: Don't. There is nothing more useless than threads executing in lockstep, because the entire point of threading is to decouple execution. Threads tightly synchronized like that will perform much worse than single-threaded code on a general-purpose processor (unlike a GPGPU). If you *abolutely must* have threads run in lockstep (and you don't), you can synchronize them with `pthread_barrier_wait()`.

Comment: I don't have semaphor.h so I can't use that feature.
Look, can you explain to me why this code doesn't work (because you still haven't)
And, if you know, can you tell me how I can achieve this lock/step functionality

Comment: @EOF 
The whole point of lock step execution is for game engines and such.
When you want 16.6666 milliseconds of graphics API, physics simulation, game logic, and AI to be executed in parallel.
But you need them to synchronize with each other once per frame.

Comment: We seem to be back at the "reading comprehension" problem again: semaphor**e**.h. Also, 16 ms is an eternity for a modern processor, I wouldn't call that lockstep (at a conservative 1.5GHz, 2 instructions/cycle, 16 ms allow 48 million instructions to be executed on a single thread in that time).

Comment: The game example is exactly where you'd use `pthread_barrier_wait()` to have the threads synchronise together at the end of frame.

Comment: I am using the (corrected) implementation of this feature in my Programming language's standard library. I had to go back here to see if I needed to provide attribution for anything I used- and it looks like I don't. Looking back at this post, it's amazing how incredibly rude you people were, especially you @EOF. I hope that you have changed as a person in these years.

What manner of foolishness is it to attack someone's reading comprehension when replying to a help post? You ought to be ashamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, it sounds like what you're really looking for is a barrier.  Nevertheless, I answer the question as posed.

> Yes, the C++ implementation works. Yes, the C++ implementation is
> nearly identical to this one, but I had to cast
> PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER and PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER in c and pass
> this as the first argument to every function. I spent a while trying
> to debug this (short of whipping out gdb) to no avail.

That seems unlikely.  There are data races and undefined behavior all over the code presented, whether interpreted as C or as C++.

#### General design

Since you provide an explicit `lock()` function, which seems reasonable, you should provide an explicit `unlock()` function as well.  Any other functions that expect to be called with the mutex locked should return with the mutex locked, so that the caller can explicitly pair `lock()` calls with `unlock()` calls.  Failure to adhere to this pattern invites bugs.

In particular, `step()` should not unlock the mutex unless it also locks it, but I think a non-locking version will suit the purpose.

#### Initialization

> I had to cast PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER and PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER in c

No, you didn't, because you ***can't***, at least not if `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t` are structure types.  Initializers for structure types are not values.  They do not have types and cannot be cast.  But you *can* form compound literals from them, and that is what you have inadvertently done.  **This is not a conforming way to assign a value to a `pthread_mutex_t` or a `pthread_cond_t`**.<sup>*</sup> The initializer macros are designated for use only in initializing variables in their declarations.  That's what "initializer" means in this context.

**Example:**

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

**Example:**

```
struct {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t  cv;
} example = { PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER };
```

To initialize a mutex or condition variable object in any other context requires use of the corresponding initialization function, `pthread_mutex_init()` or `pthread_cond_init()`.

#### Data races

Non-atomic accesses to shared data by multiple concurrently-running threads must be protected by a mutex or other synchronization object if any of the accesses are writes (exceptions apply for accesses to mutexes and other synchronization objects themselves).  Shared data in your example include file-scope variables `a1` and `a2`, and most of the members of your `lsthread` instances.  Your `lsthread_func` and driver both sometimes fail to lock the appropriate mutex before accessing those shared data, and some of the accesses involved are indeed writes, so undefined behavior ensues.  Observing unexpected values of `a1` and `a2` is an entirely plausible manifestation of that undefined behavior.

#### Condition variable usage

The thread that calls `pthread_cond_wait()` must do so while holding the specified mutex locked.  Your `lsthread_func()` does not adhere to that requirement, so more  undefined behavior ensues.  If you're very lucky, that might manifest as an immediate spurious wakeup.

And speaking of spurious wakeups, you do not guard against them.  If one does occur then `lsthread_func()` blithely goes on to perform another iteration of its loop.  To avoid this, you need shared data somewhere upon which the *condition* of the condition variable is predicated.  The standard usage of a CV is to check that predicate before waiting, and to loop back and check it again after waking up, repeatedly if necessary, not proceeding until the predicate evaluates true.

#### Synchronized stepping

The worker threads do not synchronize directly with each other, so only the driver can ensure that one does not run ahead of the other.  **But it doesn't.**  The driver does nothing at all to ensure that either thread has completed a step before signaling both threads to perform another.  Condition variables do not store signals, so if, by some misfortune of scheduling or by the nature of the tasks involved, one thread should get a step ahead of the other, it will remain ahead until and unless the error happens to be spontaneously balanced by a misstep on the other side.

Probably you want to add a `lsthread_wait()` function that waits for the thread to complete a step.  That would involve use of the CV from the opposite direction.

Overall, you could provide (better) for single-stepping by

- Adding a member to type `lsthread` to indicate whether the thread should be or is executing a step *vs*. whether it is between steps and should wait.

  ```
  typedef struct {
      // ...
      _Bool should_step;
  } lsthread;
  ```
- Adding the aforementioned `lsthread_wait()`, maybe something like this:

  ```
  // The calling thread must hold t->myMutex locked
  void lsthread_wait(lsthread *t) {
      // Wait, if necessary, for the thread to complete a step
      while (t->should_step) {
          pthread_cond_wait(&t->myCond, &t->myMutex);
      }
      assert(!t->should_step);

      // Prepare to perform another step
      t->should_step = 1;
  }
  ```
- That would be paired with a revised version of `lsthread_func()`:

  ```
   void* lsthread_func(void* me_void){
       lsthread* me = (lsthread*) me_void;
       if (!me) pthread_exit(NULL);

       lock(me); // needed to protect access to *me members and to globals
       while (!me->shouldKillThread && me->execute) {
           while (!me->should_step && !me->shouldKillThread) {
               int ret = pthread_cond_wait(&(me->myCond), &(me->myMutex));
               if (ret) {
                   unlock(me);  // mustn't forget to unlock
                   pthread_exit(NULL);
               }
           }
           assert(me->should_step || me->shouldKillThread);

           if (!me->shouldKillThread && me->execute) {
               me->execute();
           }

           // Mark and signal step completed
           me->should_step = 0;
           ret = pthread_cond_broadcast(me->myCond);
           if (ret) break;
       }
       unlock(me);

       pthread_exit(NULL);
   }
  ```
- Modifying `step()` to avoid it unlocking the mutex.
- Modifying the driver loop to use the new wait function appropriately

  ```
  lock(&t1);
  lock(&t2);
  do {
      printf("\n%u: a1 = %d, a2 = %d", i++, (int) a1, (int) a2);
      fflush(stdout);
      step(&t1);
      step(&t2);
      lsthread_wait(&t1);
      lsthread_wait(&t2);
  } while (a1 < a2);  // both locks must be held when this condition is evaluated
  kill_lsthread_islocked(&t2);
  kill_lsthread_islocked(&t1);
  unlock(&t2);
  unlock(&t1);
  ```

That's not necessarily all the changes that would be required, but I think I've covered the all the key points.

#### Final note

The above suggestions are based on the example program, in which different worker threads do not access any of the same shared data.  That makes it feasible to use per-thread mutexes to protect the shared data they do access.  If the workers accessed any of the same shared data, and those or any thread running concurrently with them modified that same data, then per-worker-thread mutexes would not offer sufficient protection.

---

<sup>*</sup> And if `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t` were pointer or integer types, which is allowed, then the compiler would have accepted the assignments in question without a cast (which would actually *be* a cast in that case), but those assignments still would be non-conforming as far as pthreads is concerned.

Comment: Thanks.
On the Initializer bit,
Yes I was aware that I formed compound literals.
But I refer to any (type)<something> as "casting" since it *looks* like a C-style cast.

Comment: The general design was as such:
Lock should guarantee that the threads are not running after returning.
Step should allow the threads to execute, and shall have executed before the next invocation of Lock
This is useful for game engines and such where it is typical to have to synchronize data between worker threads, but only once per game tick.

Comment: Ultimately I ended up writing an implementation based on Barriers. I also backported the barrier implementation to my C++ version, since it seems to be more stable (I did more testing, the C++ version *did* have bugs, but they didn't crop up before as I had never tested it as thoroughly)

Comment: My implementation has been published as free software